# C process and forking process

Tags: c, process

Im studying Operative Systems and can't really grasp this piece of code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int pid;
    int i;

    pid = fork();

    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1: 
            perror ("Error \n");
            break;

        case 0: 
            for(i=1; i < 11; i++)
                printf ("Im the son %d, My father is %d - Loop %d \n", getpid(), getppid(), i);
            break;

        default: 
            for(i=1; i < 11; i++)
                printf ("Im the father %d and my father is %d - Loop %d \n", getpid(), getppid(), i);

            wait(NULL);
            printf("End of the father process %d - My son process %d have finished.\n", getpid(), pid);
            break;
    }

}
```

I understand that you fork (create a duplicate of the process), if everything went fine (different from -1) then it loops in a `for` ten times and then breaks, what I dont understand is how the son can go back to the `for`, I mean if it is 0 (the son) the you printf "it's the son X and my father is Y" and then breaks. how is it that it loops both of them 10 times?.

Comment: The child process executes the 'case 0:' clause and the the original (parent) process executes the 'default:' clause. They both run concurrently (although the order in which the code executes is undefined).

Comment: Thanks Mick, now it is undefined, but what gives? I mean at some point they end (mixed maybe). Is there any part of the Operative System that gives priority over a process than the other one?

Comment: I actually misunderstood your question. Riley got it right.

Answer (score 2):

`for()` without `{}` only executes the next line repeatedly.

```
for(i=1; i < 11; i++)
    printf();
break;
```

is the same as

```
for(i=1; i < 11; i++) {
    printf();
}
break;
```

Comment: Thanks Riley, now I have one more question, how is it that it's mixed? Who gives priority over one process than the other? is there any algorithm in the OS that resolves this?

Comment: The two processes will be switched in and out of the CPU. Normally neither has priority over the other. One of the biggest jobs of the OS is to decide which process to run when. Google `cpu scheduler`.